# How to use a bash script variable with sed

Tags: bash, scripting, sed

I execute the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
version=$1
echo $version
sed 's/\${version.number}/$version/' template.txt > readme.txt
```

I'm expecting to replace all instances of ${version.number} with the contents of the variable "version". Instead the literal text $version is being inserted.

What do I need to do to make sed use the current value of $version instead?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
sed "s/\${version.number}/$version/" template.txt > readme.txt
```

Only double quotes do dollar-sign replacement.  That also means single quotes don't require the dollar sign to be escaped.

Comment: But the dollar sign has to be escaped because the expression is treated as a regex by `sed`. So I think it should be `\\$`.

Comment: @Philipp, actually the `$` sign is only an anchor when it's the last character of the regex (or possibly subexpression).  But I admit I got lucky. ;)  You can optionally add an escaped slash, but then it's `\\\$`.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11209079/376454) worked better for me.

Answer (score 4):

You could also simply unquote the variables

```
sed 's/'${version.number}'/'$version'/' template.txt > readme.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit old, but it might still be helpful...
For me it worked using a double escape as Philip said (and escaping parenthesis, if you use them...):

```
#!/bin/bash
LIVE_DB_NAME='wordpress';
STAGING='staging';
sed -r "s/define\('DB_NAME', '[a-zA-Z0-9]+'\);/define('DB_NAME', '\\${LIVE_DB_NAME}');/" ${STAGING}/wp-config.php >tmp1;
```