# Bash variable in sed command

Tags: bash, sed, expand

I need to add an header recursively to several file according to the name of the file.

So I have tried:

```
for i in *file 
do     
sed -i '1 i \A;B;C;D;E;F;G;H;${i%??}' a_${i} > header_a_${i}
done
```

the problem is that the variable reflecting the name of the file does not expand and in the header I have ${i%??} instead of part of the name file (%?? is to remove some ending characters).

Any help would be great.

Comment: exact dupe [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3204302/495451) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11146098/495451)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use double quotes:

```
    sed '1 i\
A;B;C;D;E;F;G;H;'"${i%??}" a_${i} > header_a_${i}
```

It doesn't make any sense to use -i and to redirect the output, so I've omitted -i.  Also, I've added an escaped newline after the insert command.  Some sed do not require the newline, but many do.  However, it seems odd to use sed for this.  Instead, just do:

```
for i in *file; do     
  { echo "A;B;C;D;E;F;G;H;${i%??}"; cat a_${i}; } > header_a_${i}
done
```