# sed will not place variable in to replacment line

Tags: sed, openstack

I have a very simple sed line to help do instal of Glance for openstack.

```
sudo sed -i \
's|identity_uri = http://127.0.0.1:35357|identity_uri = http://$MY_PRIVATE_IP:35357|g' \
/etc/glance/glance-api.conf
```

The part with the $MY_PRIVATE_IP shows up in the config file just as that not the value of 10.0.0.35 which is set in the tty.

If I do an echo you see the correct value.

```
echo $MY_PRIVATE_IP
10.0.0.35
```

Not sure what I am missing in the sed statement to make sure the value is inserted in to the config.

Comment: Does my answer help? If yes, could you please put closure to your question by accepting it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use double quotes in your sed.

```
sudo sed -i \
"s|identity_uri = http://127.0.0.1:35357|identity_uri = http://$MY_PRIVATE_IP:35357|g" \
/etc/glance/glance-api.conf
```

I also noticed a different way you could make your variable work. See this question: [How to use a bash script variable with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204302/how-to-use-a-bash-script-variable-with-sed)